# Problem in adding data to an array in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am grappling with adding an NSData object to a NSMutable array.
The code is executing fine but it is not adding the objects in the array.The code is as follows:

```
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);

int i=0;

    do{

        if([[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:imageData])
        {
            [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
        else 
        {
            [tempArray addObject:imageData];
            //NSLog(@"ANURAG %@",[tempArray objectAtIndex:0]);
        }
    }while(i<[tempArray count]) ;
```

The NSLog statement shows the object added is null however the value of imageData is not null.

I have defined the tempArray as a static memeber of the class in which this code is written.

Is it because of the size of the data object as it is the data of an image?

Comment: Could you limit yourself to just one (1) ! or ? per sentence?  Multiple !!!'s and ???'s make your question look silly and unprofessional.

Comment: Is this supposed to be some kind of infinite loop? What happens if you log tempArray instead of [tempArray objectAtIndex:0] ? Still null, huh?

Comment: dont look at the value of i

that i just inserted for testing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you initialize tempArray before this code section? You cannot add objects to an uninitialized array.

```
tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom.
But now the problem is the application is getting crashed on adding the imageData to an array.Is the size of data object must be limited???
The exception is

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'

Comment: Because you do `[[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:imageData]` when the array is empty.